# Next.js disable caching for server function in production

Tags: typescript, next.js

In next.js 14 I have a page that uses default Server-side Rendering (SSR) to fetch some data and pass it on to its client components.

```
export default async function Page() {
  const magazines = await getMagazines(true);

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    >
      <ContextProvider>
        <Header />
        <Content magazines={magazines} />
      </ContextProvider>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The getMagazines function also runs on the server and uses prisma to load magazines from the db.

```
export async function getMagazines(
  includeUnpublished: boolean = false
): Promise<Magazine[] | null> {
  const magazines = await prisma.magazine.findMany({
    where: includeUnpublished ? {} : { isPublished: true },
    orderBy: [
      {
        year: "desc",
      },
      {
        number: "desc",
      },
    ],
  });

  return magazines || null;
}
```

This works excellent in local development. However, in my production environment f.e. when deleting a magazine, it still keeps showing all the magazines up until hours later.

I am suspecting next.js uses one of the caching behaviours described in this article: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching but I cannot figure out which one to disable here..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `revalidatePath` to revalidate that specific page. Essentially, the `revalidatePath` allows you to purge cached data on-demand for a specific path.

So let's say you want to revalidate the data cache of your magazines page, you'll do `revalidatePath('/magazines')`. And by doing this it will revalidate or re-fetch the data when a user visit that page after the revalidation.

But make sure to put that `revalidatePath()` inside your code that deletes the magazines, because you would want to invalidate the cache only when you make changes to the magazines data, in your case when you delete a magazine.

So basically this is how probably your code will look like:

```
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'

export async function deleteMagazine( magazineId : string) {
  try {
    // do your prisma magic here and delete that magazine
    // after that revalidate that path and tell nextjs to refetch the data again
    revalidatePath('/magazines')
  }
  catch (e) {
    // handle any errors if there are any
  }
}
```

But remember `revalidatePath` only invalidates the cache when the included path is next visited.

[`revalidatePath` API Refrence](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath)